# Under- and Overfull Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf, scaling, overfull, underfull

Im trying for DAYS now to correctly format my two Diagrams. I tried plenty of solutions on this Page, but nothing worked (Adjustbox, environ, scale,...)
The first one is this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        bar width=17pt,
        width = 0.7\textwidth,
        %
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align=center,
        nodes near coords style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/precision=0,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
            rotate=90,
            anchor=east,
            color=white
            },
        bar shift=0pt,
        %
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=left,
        %
        ylabel=Anzahl erfasster Fälle,
        ymin=0,
        ytick={0,20000,40000,60000,80000,100000,120000,140000},
        yticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/precision=0,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill
        },
        scaled y ticks=false,
        enlargelimits=auto,
        %
        /pgf/number format/use comma,
        x = 22pt,
        symbolic x coords ={2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021},
        xtick = {2007,...,2021},
        x tick label style={rotate=30,anchor=north east},
        ]
        \addplot[fill=blue!70] coordinates {
          (2007,34180)
          (2008,37900)
          (2009,50254)
          (2010,59839)
          (2011,59494)
          (2012,63959)
          (2013,64426)
          (2014,49925)
          (2015,45793)
          (2016,82649)
          (2017,85960)
          (2018,87106)
          (2019,100514)
          (2020,108474)
          (2021,124137)
        };
      \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Error is:

```
Overfull \hbox (12.0321pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 141--142
```

141 is `\end{tikzpicture}` and 142 is `\end{figure}`
It is visually visible, that it stands out of the textwidth. Strangly, the ´width´ i setted adjusts the height of the diagram. So if i scale the 0.7 to 0.9 for example, the diagram increases in height.

And the second is this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xbar,
            width=\textwidth/1.5, 
            height=10cm,
            %enlarge x limits=0.5,
            xlabel={Anteil der Befragten},
            xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},
            axis y line*=left,
            axis x line*=bottom,
            xmin=0,
            %tick pos=left,
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
            symbolic y coords={Man-in-the-Middle Angriffe, Cross-Site-Scripting, \Gls{sql}-Injection, Ransomware, Angriffe auf Passwörter, Phishing-Angriffe, Spoofing, \Gls{ddos}-Attacken, Infizierung mit Schadsoftware bzw. Malware},
            ytick=data,
            y tick label style={
                %rotate=30,
                anchor=east,
                text width=5cm,
                align=right
            }
        ]
        \addplot[fill=blue!70] coordinates {
            (31,Infizierung mit Schadsoftware bzw. Malware) 
            (27,\Gls{ddos}-Attacken)
            (20,Spoofing)
            (18,Phishing-Angriffe)
            (18,Angriffe auf Passwörter)
            (18,Ransomware)
            (17,\Gls{sql}-Injection)
            (9,Cross-Site-Scripting)
            (5,Man-in-the-Middle Angriffe)
        };
        \end{axis}
\end{figure}
```

Error here is:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 185--185
Underfull \hbox (badness 2005) in paragraph at lines 185--185
Underfull \hbox (badness 5359) in paragraph at lines 185--185
Underfull \hbox (badness 1052) in paragraph at lines 185--185
```

185 is `\end{axis}`

Im getting pretty frustrated with this. Both are my first diagrams ever in Latex. Am i missing something very obvious? Im using Overleaf for Latex, if this matters.

Edit: Example:

```
\documentclass{scrreport}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%Encoding
\usepackage[shorthands=off,english,ngerman]{babel}%Sprache
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}% nutzung von acronymen
\usepackage[chapter]{minted}% minted für code listing sieht einfach schöner aus
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
  scaled y ticks=false
}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newacronym{ddos}{DDOS}{Distributed Denial of Service}
\newacronym{sql}{SQL}{Structured Query Language}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xbar,
            width=\textwidth/1.5, 
            height=10cm,
            %enlarge x limits=0.5,
            xlabel={Anteil der Befragten},
            xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},
            axis y line*=left,
            axis x line*=bottom,
            xmin=0,
            %tick pos=left,
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
            symbolic y coords={Man-in-the-Middle Angriffe, Cross-Site-Scripting, \Gls{sql}-Injection, Ransomware, Angriffe auf Passwörter, Phishing-Angriffe, Spoofing, \Gls{ddos}-Attacken, Infizierung mit Schadsoftware bzw. Malware},
            ytick=data,
            y tick label style={
                %rotate=30,
                anchor=east,
                text width=5cm,
                align=right
            }
        ]
        \addplot[fill=blue!70] coordinates {
            (31,Infizierung mit Schadsoftware bzw. Malware) 
            (27,\Gls{ddos}-Attacken)
            (20,Spoofing)
            (18,Phishing-Angriffe)
            (18,Angriffe auf Passwörter)
            (18,Ransomware)
            (17,\Gls{sql}-Injection)
            (9,Cross-Site-Scripting)
            (5,Man-in-the-Middle Angriffe)
        };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        bar width=17pt,
        width = 0.7\textwidth,
        %
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align=center,
        nodes near coords style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/precision=0,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
            rotate=90,
            anchor=east,
            color=white
            },
        bar shift=0pt,
        %
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=left,
        %
        ylabel=Anzahl erfasster Fälle,
        ymin=0,
        ytick={0,20000,40000,60000,80000,100000,120000,140000},
        yticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/precision=0,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill
        },
        scaled y ticks=false,
        enlargelimits=auto,
        %
        /pgf/number format/use comma,
        x = 22pt,
        symbolic x coords ={2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021},
        xtick = {2007,...,2021},
        x tick label style={rotate=30,anchor=north east},
        ]
        \addplot[fill=blue!70] coordinates {
          (2007,34180)
          (2008,37900)
          (2009,50254)
          (2010,59839)
          (2011,59494)
          (2012,63959)
          (2013,64426)
          (2014,49925)
          (2015,45793)
          (2016,82649)
          (2017,85960)
          (2018,87106)
          (2019,100514)
          (2020,108474)
          (2021,124137)
        };
      \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. Please add a complete **Minimal Working Example** (documentclass and used packages as well as `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`) that we can copy and test.

Comment: an overfull box means something is wider than the place that it is placed, but as you have not provided an example that produces that message, it is hard to help. Please provide a small but complete example

Comment: Okay, give me some minutes, im creating one

Comment: The problem of the first bar chart is probably: `x = 22pt`.

Comment: Added the example and removed as many Packages as i think made sense. Removing T1 changes the Error

Comment: In the first bar chart with the x label **Anteil der Befragten** the `symbolic y coords` are too wide. I would remove `text width=5cm` and insert some line breaks manually. I also recommend using only the abbreviations DDOS and SQL and omitting the spelled out variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility to fix your problems (see commands in the code):

```
\documentclass{scrreport}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%Encoding
\usepackage[shorthands=off,english,ngerman]{babel}%Sprache
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}% nutzung von acronymen
\usepackage[chapter]{minted}% minted für code listing sieht einfach schöner aus
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
  scaled y ticks=false
}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newacronym{ddos}{DDOS}{Distributed Denial of Service}
\newacronym{sql}{SQL}{Structured Query Language}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xbar,
            width=\textwidth/1.5,% recommendation: use X/\textwidth 
            height=10cm,
            %enlarge x limits=0.5,
            xlabel={Anteil der Befragten},
            xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},
            axis y line*=left,
            axis x line*=bottom,
            xmin=0,
            %tick pos=left,
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
            symbolic y coords={Man-in-the-Middle\\Angriffe, Cross-Site-Scripting, SQL-Injection, Ransomware, Angriffe auf Passwörter, Phishing-Angriffe, Spoofing, DDOS-Attacken, Infizierung mit Schad-\\software bzw. Malware},
            ytick=data,
            y tick label style={
                %rotate=30,
%                anchor=east,   % <-- removed
%                text width=5cm,% <-- removed
                align=right
            }
        ]
        \addplot[fill=blue!70] coordinates {% <-- added line breaks manually
            (31,Infizierung mit Schad-\\software bzw. Malware) 
            (27,DDOS-Attacken)
            (20,Spoofing)
            (18,Phishing-Angriffe)
            (18,Angriffe auf Passwörter)
            (18,Ransomware)
            (17,SQL-Injection)
            (9,Cross-Site-Scripting)
            (5,Man-in-the-Middle\\Angriffe)
        };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        bar width=12pt,% <-- smaller number to get a little space between the bars
        width = 0.7\textwidth,
        %
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align=center,
        nodes near coords style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/precision=0,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
            rotate=90,
            anchor=east,
            color=white
            },
        bar shift=0pt,
        %
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=left,
        %
        ylabel=Anzahl erfasster Fälle,
        ymin=0,
        ytick={0,20000,40000,60000,80000,100000,120000,140000},
        yticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/precision=0,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill
        },
        scaled y ticks=false,
        enlargelimits=auto,
        %
        /pgf/number format/use comma,
%       x = 22pt,% <-- removed
        symbolic x coords ={2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021},
        xtick = {2007,...,2021},
        x tick label style={rotate=30,anchor=north east,font=\footnotesize},%  <-- added font=\footnotesize
        ]
        \addplot[fill=blue!70] coordinates {
          (2007,34180)
          (2008,37900)
          (2009,50254)
          (2010,59839)
          (2011,59494)
          (2012,63959)
          (2013,64426)
          (2014,49925)
          (2015,45793)
          (2016,82649)
          (2017,85960)
          (2018,87106)
          (2019,100514)
          (2020,108474)
          (2021,124137)
        };
      \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output without overfull \hbox errors.]